# Proper way for curency switch javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im starting learning javascript and I wondering what is better or most common solution for eshops that allows customers switch currency.

Is it better

a) to store price of products in ordinary html tags just like `<span class="price">34</span>` And when customer switch curency, get last price value and multiply it by difference betwen last and selected curency?

b) Or its better to create custom attributes just like `<span price="34" class="price">34</span>`and if user changes curency, then multiple price attribute with curency value and display it?

Or is there an another way how to do that?

Comment: You want to avoid multiplying money by your self. There are libraries that can convert between currencies. The number type in javascript is not a base 10 format and you will have errors if you try to do certain math.

Comment: Also, the exchange rate goes up and down. You don't want to hard-code any of that, because then you'll have to be changing it all the time. As far as I'm concerned, this is a task for the server. The most JS I'd have would be an AJAX call.